# Sharp tip in texture mode

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

When I go in texture mode, there is soft circle to paint with.

Is it possible to paint with sharp lines like squares and circles with sharp edges?

I mean sharp edges when there is **no** soft gradient between black and white texture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Circle brush

You can use **Curve** to change your tip sharpness. There are six presets for them and you can make your own as well.

**Curve types:**

[image: Curves]

### Square brush

The best way to have square tip or any other shape is to prepare one in 2D software (Krita, Gimp, InkScape, Adobe etc.)

Make tip shape white and transparent background (for convenience sake) make it pretty big for good quality (4k in my example) and save it as PNG with Transparency then setup **Texture Mask** as below:

[image: square]

### Blend file (square tip texture packed)

[image]